# C# 2D Game Engine Development

Tags: c#, game-engine

I have been wanting to develop a 2D game in C#. Now, I have already done this in Java before, but I cannot seem to find anything with similar syntax.

The main Game class of my Java game engine works as follows:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import GameState.GameStateManager;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
    //Dimensions
    public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;//(HEIGHT/9)*16;//360
    public static final int SCALE = 3;

    //Game Thread
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private int FPS = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000/FPS;

    //Image
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    //Game State Manager
    private GameStateManager gsm;

    public GamePanel()
    {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify()
    {
        super.addNotify();
        if(thread == null)
        {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            addKeyListener(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    private void init()
    {
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        running = true;
        gsm = new GameStateManager();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        init();

        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;

        //Game loop
        while(running)
        {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            update();
            draw();
            drawToScreen();

            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

            if(wait <= 0)
            {
                wait = 1;
            }
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void update()
    {
        gsm.update();
    }
    private void draw()
    {
        gsm.draw(g);
    }
    private void drawToScreen()
    {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key){}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key)
    {
        gsm.keyPressed(key.getKeyCode());
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key)
    {
        gsm.keyReleased(key.getKeyCode());
    }
}
```

Are there any decent tutorials on the engine development out there? And is there a way I can implement the above code in C#? I would like to avoid using an pre-made engine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/). It is the open source implementation of XNA, which has been discontinued. It runs similar to your Java code, with a main game loop and methods that run on every cycle, so it shouldn't be hard to port over, especially if you are just starting. It is worthy to note that MonoGame is open source and cross-platform.

Comment: I would like to avoid using a pre-made game engine if possible.

Comment: @GenericMadman It isn't a pre-made game engine, its more like a framework for you to write your own engine.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have a look. :)

Comment: I may use this. But is there a way of implementing what I have made in Java in c# without any other frameworks?

Comment: What kind of game will you write with it? With winforms you can do the stuff in your code, but it'll be rather slow and not very responsive for most action type games. Pacman is ok but Defender (with its scrolling backplane) will not work well..